# Getting all possible two column subsets

Tags: r

I am a relative newbie to R and I am now very close to being finished with a rather long script with many thanks to everyone who helped me thus far at various steps. I have another point I am stuck on. I have simplified the issue to this:

```
Dataset1
ax ay
1  3
2  4

Dataset2
bx by
5   7
6   8

A <- dataset1
B <- dataset2
a <- 2 #number of columns
b <- 1:2
```

(my datasets will vary in number of columns and so I need to be able to vary this factor)

I want this answer in any order (i.e. all possible combinations of two columns one from each of the two datasets) like this or equivalent.

```
[[1]]
1  5
2  6

[[2]]
1  7
2  8

[[3]]
3  5
4  6

[[4]]
3  7
4  8
```

But I am not getting it. 
I tried a bunch of things and the closest to what I want was with this:

```
i <- 1
for( i in 1:a )
 {
   e <- lapply(B, function(x) as.data.frame(cbind(A, x)))
   print(e)
   i <- i+1
  }
```

Close, yes. I can take the answer and do some fiddling and subsetting but its not right and there must be an easy way to do this. I have not seen anything like this in my on line searches. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do is very similar to what you tried, use two explicit loops. However, there are still some things I would do differently:

1. Pre allocate the list space
2. Use an explicit `counter`
3. Use `drop=FALSE`

Then you can do the following.

```
A <- read.table(text = "ax ay
1  3
2  4", header = TRUE)

B <- read.table(text = "bx by
5   7
6   8", header = TRUE)

out <- vector("list", length = ncol(A) * ncol(B))
counter <- 1
for (i in 1:ncol(A)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(B)) {
        out[[counter]] <- cbind(A[,i, drop = FALSE], B[,j, drop = FALSE])
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
}
out

## [[1]]
##   ax bx
## 1  1  5
## 2  2  6
## 
## [[2]]
##   ax by
## 1  1  7
## 2  2  8
## 
## [[3]]
##   ay bx
## 1  3  5
## 2  4  6
## 
## [[4]]
##   ay by
## 1  3  7
## 2  4  8
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. I especially like the explcit counter. I feel I was onto the right thing but not all the way there and I see it now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Does something like this work for you?

```
Dataset1 <- data.frame(ax=1:2,ay=3:4)
Dataset2 <- data.frame(bx=5:6,by=7:8)

apply(
    expand.grid(seq_along(Dataset1),seq_along(Dataset2)),
    1,
    function(x) cbind(Dataset1[x[1]],Dataset2[x[2]])
     )
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
  ax bx
1  1  5
2  2  6

[[2]]
  ay bx
1  3  5
2  4  6

[[3]]
  ax by
1  1  7
2  2  8

[[4]]
  ay by
1  3  7
2  4  8
```

Comment: This works, actually quite well but I need the counter Henrik provided. I wish I could tick both as the right answer. Thank you for taking time to answer. I do appreciate it.

Comment: @NatalieBjorklund - there is almost certainly a work-around to generate a counter of sorts. The counter will end up as `length(result)` in this case. The `for(i in...)` logic in R frequently works out being more convoluted in the long run, but I do understand that this is just part of a larger script.

Comment: The counter makes sense within the longer script BUT that being said, I will be checking if I can get rid of the counter with your answer because I like less convoluted. So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, I think you can use `combn` to select the columns you want.  For instance, if wanted all combinations of 8 columns taken 2 at  at time, you could do:

```
combn(1:8, 2)
```

Which gives (in part for readability):

```
combn(1:8,2)[,c(1:5, 15:18)]
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    3    3    3    3
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    5    6    7    8
```

So then columns of this matrix can be used as the indices you want.

Comment: I don't think this will work because I have to be able to use it over and over with different datasets which may or may not have the same number of columns and I won't know anything ecept the number of columns in each dataset as it is generated. But I appreciate you taking the time to answer. Thank you.

Comment: @NatalieBjorklund For future use, as you read in each data set, you can use `ncol` to find the number of columns if that helps.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and made note of it. That will be useful in future.